# In Mac OS 10.10 Whenever I open new Terminal window some command automatically gets executed

Tags: macos, command-line

In Mac OS 10.10 Whenever I open new Terminal window some command automatically gets executed.
I don't know how it came to my Mac. Probably after installing some command line utility not sure which.
Its `head` command (don't know what it does) and it keeps running until I don't <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

Its affecting nothing yet. But feels weird.

How do I remove it? Is there something like startup commands?

**Edit**

This is my `cat ~/.bashrc`

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"


### Added by Vallabh
alias xampp='/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp'
```

Answer (score 2):

Look for the `bash` rc-scripts:

- `~/.bashrc`
- `~/.bash_profile`
- `~/.profile`
- `/etc/bash.bashrc`
- `/etc/profile`

Those script are executed by `bash` when you open a new terminal. You can search them for the `head` command to find the problem.

**By the way**: `head` is a utillity to output the first part of files, in contrary to his brother `tail`. When `head` is invoked without an argument, it reads from stdin. That blocks the terminal until 10 lines came. I think that is what happens in your case.

Comment: Minor nitpick: In contrast to most Linux/Unix systems, OS X starts a login shell when you open a Terminal window, so `~/.bashrc` isn't read. See also `man bash`, section *Invocation*.

Comment: I've added code from `.bashrc` to the question please check.. there nothing related to `head` i think..

Comment: I had this issue with HEAD. Updating RVM (which i see you use) solved the issue for me.